# Как обработать нажатие на пункт меню при использовании Android navigation component

Tags: android, android-navigation-view, android-arch

Android navigation component автоматически вешает слушатели на пункты меню. Но если я хочу, например, при нажатие на пункт меню отобразить сначала тост, или диалоговое окно, как мне обработать нажатие вручную.
При использовании OnNavigationItemSelectedListener он полностью игнорирует работу Navigation component, и вешает слушатель всего меню на OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

Comment: Переопределить метод `onNavigationItemSelected`?

Comment: При переопределении, он полностью игнорирует работу android navigation component, и ставит обработчик по умолчанию на onNavigationItemSelected.

Comment: а вы пробовали возвращать true/false?

Comment: Да, пробовал, никакой реакции. Видимо navigation components может осуществлять только навигацию